# True or False questions regarding $_9$ with the irreducible polynomial $x^2 +2x+2$

Tags: discrete-mathematics, polynomials, finite-fields, inverse, irreducible-polynomials

Let $_9$ be constructed with the irreducible polynomial $x^2 +2x+2$.

For $a,b \in _3$ we write $ax+b \in _9$ for $ab$.

In our exam we had to find out whether the following are true or false.
I know the answers, but I don't understand how one can find out.

$$22 \text{ is the inverse of } 11 \text{ -> True}$$
$$22 \text{ is the negative of } 11 \text{ -> True}$$

$$\text{For random } a \in _9 \setminus \{00\} \text{ it holds that } a^3 =01 \text{ -> False}$$
$$\text{For random } a \in _9 \setminus \{00\} \text{ it holds that } 3 \cdot a  =01 \text{ -> False} $$

I just know that $_3[x](x^2+1)$ is a finite field with $9$ elements and $_9$ is isomorphic to it, but what is the approach when trying to figure out which of the above are true/false?

If the polynomial was $x^2+x+2$, then the answers would be False, True, False, False.

Comment: For example, for the first, just multiply: $(2x+2)(x+1) = 2x^2+4x+2 = x^2+2x = -2 = 1$ using $x^2+2x+2=0$ and the fact that the field has characteristic 3.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note that $$\Bbb{F}_9=\Bbb{Z}_3[x]/\langle x^2+2x+2 \rangle=\{ax+b \, | \, a,b \in \Bbb{Z}_3 \text{ and } x^2+2x+2 \equiv 0\}.$$
The notation you are using is a tad confusing: when you write $22$, I am assuming it refers to $2x+2$.

To check if $22=2x+2$ and $11=x+1$ are inverses of each other, we do the following:
\begin{align*}
(2x+2)(x+1)&=2(x+1)^2\\
&=2(x^2+2x+1)\\
&=2(-2+1) && (\because x^2+2x+2 \equiv 0)\\
&=-2\\
&=1 && (\because -2 \equiv 1 \text { in } \Bbb{Z}_3)
\end{align*}
Thus $2x+2$ and $x+1$ are inverses.

**Added information:**

Let $\alpha=ax+b \in \Bbb{F}_9 \setminus \{0\}$. Suppose $\alpha^3 =1$ for all such $\alpha$'s, then that would mean the order of all non-zero and non-identity elements is $3$. But the order of the multiplicative group $\Bbb{F}_9^{\times}=\Bbb{F}_9\setminus \{0\}$ is $8$ and $3$ does not divide $8$, so this is not possible by Lagrange's Theorem.

*But here is an alternate way (simple calculation) to check this without invoking Lagrange's theorem*

Let's take $\alpha=x$ (in your notation it is $10$). Then
\begin{align*}
x^3 & = x(x^2)\\
&=x(-2x-2) && (\because x^2+2x+2 \equiv 0)\\
&=x^2+x\\
&=-2x-2+x\\
&=-x-2\\
& =2x+1.
\end{align*}
THus $x^3 \not \equiv 1$.

Hopefully you can take the rest from here.

Comment: Thank you for your reply, but I still don't quite get how to continue with that

Comment: @JavaTeachMe2018 I have added something. Hopefully that can help..